# Add a random div on html page with javascript (with no repeat)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the code which does not work (Nothing is added). The first line will work if I remove the comment. I suppose the variable result is not taking a number or something else. I don't really understand why.

```
$(document).ready(function () 
    //document.getElementById(1).style.display = "inline-block";
    // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqLS4oyJ8cA
    array.prototype.randsplice = function(){
        var rndNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*this.length);
        var lstSplice = this.splice(rndNumber,1);
        return lstSplice;
    }
    var lstNumber = new Array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
    var result = lstNumber.randsplice();
    document.getElementById(result).style.display = "inline-block";
    var result = lstNumber.randsplice();
    document.getElementById(result).style.display = "inline-block";
    var result = lstNumber.randsplice();
    document.getElementById(result).style.display = "inline-block";
});
```

I tried to followed this interesting link: [Randomly Empty a Javascript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26876906/randomly-empty-a-javascript-array)
but without success.
(obviously the style display is originally set to none for all div.)

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, I noticed 2 mistakes so far;

1. You're missing `{` in `$(document).ready(function ()`. Which should be `$(document).ready(function () {`
2. `array.prototype.randsplice` should be `Array.prototype.randsplice`

And beware that you need [jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/) to run this script. And here's the final [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eLhLkg69/)

Comment: Thanks. The missing { was actually a copy paste error, but I really forgotten the uppercase A. I knew about JQuery. It is working perfectly now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `Array.prototype.randsplice`, with a capital A.

Comment: As in my comment above, the mistake was the uppercase A. Thanks.